# Android SubMenu icon disappear when i cread a menu dynamically

Tags: java, android, html, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying create a menu list dynamically, i was able to create the menu option but every time i run my code the icon for the main item disappear: here is my code sample:

```
private static final int SUB_Menu_ONE = R.menu.settings;
    private static final int SUB_Menu_TWO = R.menu.settings + 1;
    private static final int SUB_Menu_THREE= R.menu.settings + 2;
    private static final int SUB_Menu_FOUR = R.menu.settings + 3; 



 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    return true;
}
//    private Menu menu;
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    menu.clear();


       menu.add(0, SUB_Menu_ONE, Menu.NONE, "Sub Menu Item 0");
       menu.add(0, SUB_Menu_TWO, Menu.NONE, "Sub Menu Item 1");    
        menu.add(0, SUB_Menu_THREE, Menu.NONE, "Sub Menu Item 2");       
         menu.add(0, SUB_Menu_FOUR, Menu.NONE, "Sub Menu Item 3");

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent inent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case SUB_Menu_ONE:
```

//          doStuff();
                break;
            case SUB_Menu_TWO:
     //          doStuff();
                break;
            case SUB_Menu_THREE:
   //          doStuff();
                break;
            case SUB_Menu_FOUR:
       //          doStuff();
                break;
            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

```
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is my XML Layout for Menu settings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/cuslistticketbutton"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/custabview"
        compat:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        >
                <!--<menu>-->
                    <!--<item-->
                        <!--android:id="@+id/menu_addticket"-->
                        <!--android:showAsAction="never"-->
                        <!--android:icon="@drawable/add_tickets"-->
                        <!--android:title=""-->
                        <!--compat:ignore="AppCompatResource,HardcodedText" />-->

                <!--</menu>-->

</item>


</menu>
```

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the icon programmatically.

```
   menu.add(0, SUB_Menu_ONE, Menu.NONE, "PREMIUM (Live Video & Audio)").setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: i have try the code earlier  but the icon is still not displaying, i have try all the tricks i know but still is zero @Dinesh Bob

Comment: You should call super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(); inside onPrePareOptionsMenu. not super.onCreateOptionsMenu();

Comment: can you move all the code present inside onPrepareOptionsMenu() to the onCreateOptionsMenu(), and try.

Comment: yeah i have try is still not working bro @Dinesh Bob

Comment: i just edited my question to add my Menu XML Settings Item

Comment: just curious to know the use case. You have the menu in xml first. Then you clear everything from the menu. And adding the menu items programmatically. what is the use case?

Comment: BTW, is this code present in a Fragment? or in Activity?

Comment: If its a Fragment, then you have to call setHasOptionsMenu(true); inside onCreate() of Fragment.

Comment: The code is inside activity, the use case is I want to add the item as submenu item to the existing xml menu item, it add but is clearing the exist on one I guess that is the case